# How to override Razor's behavior for tilde '~'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Since MVC version 4 it is not required to write `src="@Url.Content("~...")"`. Razor understands tilde and we can simply write `src="~..."`.

I mistakenly though Razor calls `UrlHelper.Content()` behind the scenes where instance comes from WebViewPage.Url property.

Unfortunately Razor behaves [elsewise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626825/how-to-inject-descendant-urlhelper-class-into-webviewpage-to-enable-cache-bustin/26627275#26627275): `Content()` method is not get called.

As I substitute default pages' `UrlHelper` with my own implementation, the results of calling `Content()` and simply writing url with tilde differ. Therefore I need consistency.

How to override Razor's behavior for tilde?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's wrong with the behavior of `~` as it stands? i.e. what problem are you trying to solve? If you just want a literal `~` maybe `Html.Raw` will help you.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: See the linked question.